# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions if merge instead of save NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: java, hibernate

When I am trying to save a new object using create case method..error is coming at session .saveORUpdate(createcasevalueentity)... I.E. illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open session

@Override
    public Map createCase(Patientcase createCase, Integer patientID, String userName 
            // changes by sahil.sharma08 start here
            /* ,List surgeonsID,
            List anesthesiologistID, Integer specialityID, Integer operationTheaterNoID
            // changes by sahil.sharma08 start here
             */) throws Exception
    {

```
    LOGGER.info("Logger Name: " + LOGGER.getName());
    Session session = null;
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Patient createPatientEntity;
    try 
    {
        // opens a new session from the session factory
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtilities.createSessionFactory();

        // For logging audit record
        AuditLogInterceptor interceptor = new AuditLogInterceptor();
        session = sessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor(interceptor).openSession();
        interceptor.setSession(session);
        interceptor.setUserName(userName);
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        createPatientEntity = (Patient) session.get(Patient.class, patientID);
        createCase.setPatient(createPatientEntity);

        if (createPatientEntity == null)
        {
            result.put("Error", "Patient ID does not Exist");
            return result;
        }
        // changes by sahil.sharma08 start here
        //Long caseID = createCase.getCaseId();
        // changes by sahil.sharma08 end here

        Query query = session.createQuery("delete FROM Casevalues cve WHERE cve.patientcase.caseId = ?");
        // changes by sahil.sharma08 start here
        //query.setParameter(0, caseID);
        query.setParameter(0, createCase.getCaseId());
        // changes by sahil.sharma08 end here
        query.executeUpdate();


        if(createCase.getSpeciality()!=null && !createCase.getSpeciality().equals(""))
        {
            Casevalues createCaseValuesEntity = new Casevalues();
            createCaseValuesEntity.setPatientcase(createCase);
            Entityvalues valuesEntity =(Entityvalues) session.get(Entityvalues.class, new Integer(createCase.getSpeciality()));
            createCaseValuesEntity.setEntityvalues(valuesEntity);
            session.saveOrUpdate(createCaseValuesEntity);

            createCase.setSpeciality(valuesEntity.getEntityValue());

        }



        // changes by sahil.sharma08 end here


        session.saveOrUpdate(createCase); // Persisting createCase Entity in database



        // changes by sahil.sharma08 end here


        result.put("patientId", createCase.getPatient().getPatientId().toString());
        result.put("caseId", createCase.getCaseId().toString());
        session.getTransaction().commit(); // Session commit
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if (session != null && session.getTransaction() != null)
        {
            // If transaction is open,rollback
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Exception occur", e);

        throw e;

    } 
    finally
    {
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.close(); // Session close
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```